# In Azure OpenAI Assistants when I upload a file and save it where is that file stored?

Tags: azure, azure-openai, openai-assistants-api

In Azure OpenAI Studio I am hoping to use Assistants to do data analysis, however, I need to know where those files are stored and how to delete them. When I click on add files I am offered the chance to use an already uploaded file. If I delete previously made assistants then the file remains.

Where are these files being uploaded to and how can I:

- Delete them
- Manage access to them so that only a subset of all employees can see the files.

I've tried searching the documentation on assistants but it only references files used in threads, not where they are stored. I also tried deleting assistants to see if files uploaded to them get deleted too but they don't.

Edit:

@Sampath I uploaded files from the playground under Assistants. When I click on Add Files I see previously uploaded files. I didn't follow a reference I just used the tool as I would the chatGPT interface from openAI.

[image_of_file_upload_tool_used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdgA1.png)

Comment: When you upload files to Azure OpenAI Assistants, they are stored in your Azure Blob storage account. To delete them, you can go to your Azure Blob storage account and delete the files from there. To manage access to the files, you can use Azure Blob storage's built-in access control mechanisms to restrict access to specific users or groups.

Comment: @Nick Hogan can you share the details of how you uploaded the file and in which service did you uploaded the file? The reference you followed to upload.

Comment: @arko I checked in the blob storage via the Azure Storage Explorer and could see the files uploaded to Cognitive Search (AI search) but the files uploaded to assistants weren't there. The file upload in assistants doesn't ask me to pick a storage location so do you know if there is a default?

Comment: @arko, when you say the files are saved in `"...**your** Azure Blob storage account."`, which Storage Account are you referring to? The `Assistants` area in the Azure AI Studio is where files can also be uploaded. But its quite unclear which Storage Account this is and how to delete files from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, files appear in the `Data files` tab. Sometimes, due to region restrictions, they don't appear.

[image]

So, there is no direct way to delete those files in the portal, but you can use the Python SDK or REST to `delete` them.

Below are the files I have in the existing files.

[image]

The same files are listed when using the Python SDK.

```py
import os
import json
from openai import AzureOpenAI
    
client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key="bb286...............",  
    api_version="2024-02-15-preview",
    azure_endpoint = "https://<openai_name>.openai.azure.com/"
    )
    
for i in client.files.list():
    print(i)
```

Output:

[image]

Whenever you create a file, a `file_id` is automatically generated, and you can use that ID for various operations.

To delete a file, use the code below.

`client.files.delete('file_id')`

[image]

Afterward, refresh the portal page to see the changes.

Next, to manage access, you need to restrict access to the Azure OpenAI resource itself, either by `api key` or in `IAM`. However, you cannot restrict access only to those files.